# AJAX Contact Form - Adding Fields + Multiple Forms One Page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

So I need to implement an AJAX information submit form. I'm using this example built by the guys at Treehouse… http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form

First part of the question… How do I add new fields? I've tried editing the .php .js and .html, getting them all in line to what I believe is right but upon testing my solution fails.

The fields I require… 
Name:
Location:
Post Code:
Date of Birth:
URL Link:
Message (200 words):

The second part… Can I run two of these on the same page?

Cheers in advance for any help! - you can email me garethyo@gmail.com if you want me to send code etc.

CODE BELOW —

```
                <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">

                <div class="field">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                <label for="link">Link:</label>
                <input type="text" id="link" name="link" required>
                </div>


                <div class="field">
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
                </div>

                </form>
```

JS

```
 $(formMessages).text(response);
        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#link').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');
```

PHP

```
<?php
// My modifications to mailer script from:
// http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
// Added input sanitizing to prevent injection

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "garethyo@gmail.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "A Future Bubbler… $name ";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Link: $link\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

?>

Comment: Since you have tried editing the files, add your attempted code to your question.

Comment: Added Sean, sorry about that, should've thought.

Comment: That looks like the original code. Where is your attempt at modifying/editing it? Since you want to add/modify inputs, you need to make the changes in all 3 code blocks (html, js, php).

Comment: I've added the 'link' field into the html, js and php but the email that comes through doesn't include the 'link' content.

Comment: Your php code only shows where you are using `$link` ->$email_content .= "Link: $link\n";`, but not where you set it -> `$link = $_POST['link'];`, can we assume you did that as well?

Comment: Hey Sean, I updated it with the full php code, hope that helps you and me

Comment: You never define `$link`. You need to add `$link = trim($_POST['link']);` before `$message = trim($_POST["message"]);`.

Comment: Sean! Thank you, I can see so clearly now what was wrong. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never define $link. You need to add $link = trim($_POST['link']); before $message = trim($_POST["message"]);. –  Sean Apr 4 at 20:50

— Sean, CEO Worldstar